# how can i use LZMA2 into python?

Tags: python, module, python-zipfile, lzma, pylzma

i know there is a module called ZipFile with LZMA, but how can i use LZMA2 multithread?
I've tried the ZipFile and backports modules, but (apparently) neither of the 2 have that option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in python called *py7zr* (https://pypi.org/project/py7zr/)

It currently doesn't support (and it is not said anywhere) multithreading, but it has got LZMA2 compression. To do that you can simply write that code
Install

```
!pip install py7zr
```

and then

```
import py7zr

my_filter = [{"id": py7zr.FILTER_LZMA2 , "preset": 7}]
with py7zr.SevenZipFile('target.7z', 'w', filters=my_filter) as archive:
    archive.writeall('/path/to/base_dir', 'base') # in first parameter choose what you want to store and this is it !
```